# How to find and update an item inside of a array (of an object in an array) {Accounts[x].Items[y].StatusCode = ...}

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a simple nested array (below). My goal is to represent these items in C# as 'Account' objects that contain a list of 'Item' along with the other account info. I can set up this structure just time in MongoDB but I have no idea how to update the StatusCode on a single item on a single account.

```
{  
   "Accounts":[  
      {  
         "Name":"SomeName1",
         "Email":"email1@site.com",
         "OwnedItems":[  
            {  
               "ItemId":55,
               "StatusCode":1
            },
            {  
               "ItemId":12,
               "StatusCode":2
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Name":"SomeName2",
         "Email":"email2@site.com",
         "OwnedItems":[  
            {  
               "ItemId":100,
               "StatusCode":3
            },
            {  
               "ItemId":101,
               "StatusCode":4
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My question is how would I query to find and update a specific StatusCode in with this setup?

Essentially what I want to do is the following. Of course, this following code would not actually update the DB.

```
public void Update_StatusCode(string accountName, int itemId, int newStatusCode)
{
    var foundAccount = collection.Find(Builders<AccountSave>.Filter.Eq(acc => acc.Name, accountName)).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
    foreach (var item in foundAccount.OwnedItems)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == itemId)
            item.StatusCode = newStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Edit: To clarify, I am using the 2.0 driver. Also, yes I know there are no '_id's. Being an example, assume they are used properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join conditions

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(string accountName, int itemId, int newStatusCode)
{
    var filter = Builders<Account>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Account>.Filter.Where(x => x.Name == accountName),
        Builders<Account>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.OwnedItems, x => x.ItemId == itemId));

    var update = Builders<Account>.Update.Set("OwnedItems.$.StatusCode", newStatusCode);
    await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Comment: Aha! I see now how useful .ElemMatch can be. That's interesting how the returned value of the first parameter sets the type of the next parameter. Did n't even know that was possible. I need to look into that...

Comment: For anyone who would like to know. Here is what you would do if you wanted to update the whole Element instead of just one member:

var update = Builders<Account>.Update.Set("OwnedItems.$", newItemObject);

Comment: I have the same problem, but I cannot use this solution, because I cannot find a class Builders<T>. Do I have to use a different library? At the moment I use "Official MongoDB supported BSON library. v.2.0.50727" and "Official MongoDB supported driver for MongoDB. v.2.0.50727". What do I wrong?

Comment: I have an additional nested element and can't figure out how to access it:

                        await coll.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(x => x.StoreGuid == storeGuid
                                    && x.ConfigGroup.Any(y => y.GroupName == groupName
                                            && y.Config.Any(z => z.Key == model.Key)),
                            Builders<StoreModel>.Update.Set(x => x.ConfigGroup[-1].Config[0].Value, model.Value));
I can only update the first element, not the one I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a lambda expression:

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(string accountName, int itemId, int newStatusCode)
{
    var filter = Builders<Account>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Account>.Filter.Where(x => x.Name == accountName),
        Builders<Account>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.OwnedItems, x => x.ItemId == itemId));

    // -1 means update first matching array element
    var update = Builders<Account>.Update
                 .Set(x => x.OwnedItems[-1].StatusCode, newStatusCode);

    Console.WriteLine(update.Render(collection.DocumentSerializer, collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry).ToString());
    // { "$set" : { "OwnedItems.$.StatusCode" : 123 } }

    await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Source: http://www.mattburkedev.com/updating-inside-a-nested-array-with-the-mongodb-positional-operator-in-c-number/